# How to tag docker image with docker-compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I want to build image via docker-compose and set specific tag to it. [Documentation](http://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) says:

> Compose will build and tag it with a generated name, and use that
>   image thereafter.

But I can't find a way to specify tag and for built images I always see 'latest' tag.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2092 is the issue tracking support for building the image with a different name

Answer (score 320, accepted):

It seems the docs/tool have been updated and you can now add the `image` tag to your script. This was successful for me.

Example:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:

  baggins.api.rest:
    image: my.image.name:rc2
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: app/Docker/Dockerfile.release
    ports:
      ...
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build

There is also a separate key for [Tags](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#tags).

Comment: Indeed, it says "If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image"

Comment: What an odd interface! The presence of one field inverts the semantics of another field that's at the same indentation level.

Comment: Yeah i found this concept so strange. I was expecting a `tag` option. I was trawling through the docs looking for tag to no avail

Comment: @Navin  If this isn't odd enough, try putting ```image: my.image.name:rc2``` in docker-compose.yml and ```build: .``` in docker-compose.override.yml and let docker-compose merge the two! (You get the same effect as the accepted answer)

Comment: I build/run by passing environment var OP_ENV (dev, stage, or prod). I can reference this in the tag, works beautifully for me:

`image: avail_imageresizer/build_test_uwsgi:${OP_ENV} `

Comment: The url for the spec referenced in the link above seems to have changed location to: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/build.md

Comment: Just want to make a clarification that helped me and I don't see it in any answer: `docker-compose build` will build the image/s with the name given in the `image` attribute. Hence it's no need to run `docker tag` for every image that you want to push and you can just `docker-compose push`

Comment: "If the image does not exist on the platform, Compose implementations MUST attempt to pull it based on the pull_policy. Compose implementations with build support MAY offer alternative options for the end user to control precedence of pull over building the image from source, however pulling the image MUST be the default behavior." If you don't want to pull the image, you should not use `image` property.

Answer (score 43):

Original answer *Nov 20 '15*:

No option for a specific tag as of Today. Docker compose just does its magic and assigns a tag like you are seeing. You can always have some script call `docker tag <image> <tag>` after you call docker-compose.

Now there's an option as described above or [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build)

```
build: ./dir
image: webapp:tag
```

Answer (score 36):

I'd like to add that you can also manage your tag versions through environment variables or an .env file.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

`export TAG=1.11`

Example:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:

  baggins.api.rest:
    image: my.image.name:${TAG}
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: app/Docker/Dockerfile.release
    ports:
      ...
```

`docker-compose config` to validate

In my ci pipeline my first build is tagged with a throwaway value used for running tests.  Then I change the tag to latest and rebuild again (nearly instant since it's all cached) before pushing to the registry.

Comment: instead of ```image: my.image.name:{$TAG}``` it should be ```image: my.image.name:${TAG}```

Comment: The doc your provide is deprecated. The latest one is https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/

Answer (score 14):

If you have already built your image, you can **re-tag** it by using the `docker tag` command:

```
docker tag imagename imagename:v1.0

docker tag imagename:v1.0 imagename:v1.1
```

If you have multiple tags attached to your repository, and if you want to remove one of them, you can use the `docker rmi` command:

```
$ docker rmi imagename:v1.0
Untagged imagename:v1.0
```

Reference:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/

Answer (score 8):

If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image:

```
build: ./dir
image: webapp:tag
```

This results in an image named `webapp` and tagged `tag`, built from `./dir`.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

Answer (score 8):

you can try:

```
services:
  nameis:
    container_name: hi_my
    build: .
    image: hi_my_nameis:v1.0.0
```

Answer (score 5):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image

> If the image does not exist on the platform, Compose implementations MUST attempt to pull it based on the `pull_policy`. Compose implementations with build support MAY offer alternative options for the end user to control precedence of pull over building the image from source, however pulling the image MUST be the default behavior.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#tags

> `tags` defines a list of tag mappings that MUST be associated to the build image. This list comes in addition of the `image` property defined in the service section

If `image` is specified, pulling the image will be the default behavior, thus if you want to use local image only, you should not specify `image`.

`tags` in `build` section is the correct place to specify the tag of local image.

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: ../backend.Dockerfile
      tags:
        - "myimage:mytag"
```

Comment: You need to upgrade to compose V2 to support this feature.

Answer (score 2):

it works for me: https://docs.docker.com/build/customize/bake/compose-file/#specification

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      tags:
        - spring-postgres:1.0
        - spring-postgres:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

then run `docker compose build --no-cache` output as follows:

```
> docker compose build --no-cache
[+] Building 192.9s (13/13) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 457B                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jre-focal                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.8.5-eclipse-temurin-17                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [builder 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.5-eclipse-temurin-17                                                                                           0.0s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jre-focal                                                                                      0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 1.05kB                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder 2/5] WORKDIR /code                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => [builder 3/5] COPY pom.xml pom.xml                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => [builder 4/5] COPY src .                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => [builder 5/5] RUN mvn clean -DskipTests -T 2C -X -am install                                                                                                192.5s 
 => [stage-1 2/3] COPY --from=builder /code/target/*.jar app.jar                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:a5827124abc899efcfbc8db150f72f5ff8034d1ab93418dee5c15525ae4e42a1                                                                      0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/spring-postgres-backend                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/spring-postgres:1.0                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/spring-postgres:latest                                                                                                         0.0s 

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```

above console output `spring-postgres:1.0` and `spring-postgres:latest`

Comment: `tags` property creates two images: convenent name + tag name, no? While `image` property creates only one image with tag name.

Answer (score 0):

According to official docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/

You can set an environment variable from your .env file

```
$ cat .env
TAG=v1.5
```

Then, you can retrieve it and use it as a tag for your image.

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:${TAG}"
```

You can verify it via command `docker compose convert`

```
$ docker compose convert

services:
  web:
    image: 'webapp:v1.5'
```