# Use Docker container within Azure pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, docker-image

I am trying to create an Azure pipeline configuration where the pipeline uses my local Dockerfile to get the correct image.

I have the following python package structure

```
project
│  
└───.azurepipelines
│   │   azure-pipelines.yml
│  
└───.devcontainer
    │   devcontainer.json
    │   Dockerfile
```

I have found some related [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583510/how-to-run-a-docker-container-in-azure-pipeline) on the subject, but I don't quite understand how to achieve what I want. I want the rest of the steps in the pipe to be performed within the container. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a build and point to a specific docker file with `docker-compose`.

Here is an example of that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50230608/37759

```
web:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-alpine
      context: ./web
    ports:
      - 8099:80
    depends_on:
      - database **strong text**
```

Note the `build` command along with dockerfile parameter.  It says, build project `web` using dockerfile `Dockerfile-alpine`