# Docker-compose runs 2 containers , but only one service is working?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

Last thing first :

> I want to run 2 Asp.net core apps and to be able to call each (via different port).

```
http://localhost:3333/api/values         // for webapplication3
http://localhost:5555/api/values         // for webapplication1
```

I've managed to do it partially - but it seems that only **one** is active at a time.

---

This is the dockerfile for `webapplication3` ( in  webapplication3 folder)

> ```
> FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
> WORKDIR /app
> ADD ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1 /app
> EXPOSE 80
> CMD  ["dotnet", "WebApplication3.dll"]
> ```

This is the dockerfile for `webapplication1` ( in  webapplication1 folder)

> ```
> FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
> WORKDIR /app
> ADD ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1 /app
> EXPOSE 80
> CMD  ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
> ```

The `Docker-compose.yml` file :

> ```
> version: '3.4'
>
> services:
>
>   webapplication3:
>     image: microsoft/dotnet:latest
>     build: ./WebApplication3
>     ports:
>       - "3333:80"
>
>
>
>   webapplication1:
>     image: microsoft/dotnet:latest
>     build: ./WebApplication1
>     ports:
>       - "5555:80"
> ```

Great let's build & up :

[image]

As you can see both are ON :

Let's see `docker ps` :

[image]

Now let's try to invoke :

[image]

As you can see both are working BUT I should've get DIFFERENT result !

([I've modified the actions to return different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9uou.jpg) )

I'm expecting that

`http://localhost:3333/api/values` will show `I'm response from webapplication 1`

And

`http://localhost:5555/api/values` will show `I'm response from webapplication 3`

**As the YML file is configured**

**Question:**

How can I make each endpoint to be accessed by the ports i've declared in `docker-compose` ?

Comment: sorry if I am asking a silly question but what do you mean by ''They go to the same service''?

Comment: @scipsycho I mean [this](https://i.imgur.com/CliOSp1.jpg). Both ports gives me answer from one service.  and I expect also `I"m response from webapplication 3`" when localhost:5555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the hell....

I've  figured out what was my problem.
I will explain how I got to this answer.

At first I said to myself : "Forget the yml" , let's run it manually.

> go to webapplication 1 folder ---->
>     `docker run -p 5555:80  -d 3f10b9720b26`
>
> go to webapplication 3 folder ---->
>     `docker run -p 3333:80  -d 3f10b9720b26`

[image]

And still I GOT same result !

[image]

So it's not about yml

Then I thought , "I'm overriding the same image again and again  , what if I tag each one differently ?"

[So i've modified the yml to actually work with the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37574953/859154) **AND ADD A TAG** :
(which basically creates two different images)

[image]

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  webapplication3:
    image: microsoft/dotnet:foo
    build: ./WebApplication3
    ports:
      - "3333:80"
    depends_on:
      - webapplication1


  webapplication1:
    image: microsoft/dotnet:bar
    build: ./WebApplication1
    ports:
      - "5555:80"
```

And now ..........

[image]

Solved.

Do not `run` on the same image again and again. use tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a definitive answer, because the problems might well be outside of the information your question supplies. But I can try to give you some trouble shooting tips:

1. Start your services with `docker-compose up -d`(as you probably already did)
2. check status and port forwards with `docker-compose ps`
3. Do your api checks
4. Stop one service with `docker stop webapplication1`
5. Repeat 2. & 3.

Can you still access both ports?

> As you can see both are working BUT both go to the same service !

Are 100% sure this is really the case?

Comment: I see them both with ps ...http://imgur.com/gallery/K9EkIZw - but no matter which port i run in browser , i see the same response

Comment: Btw i run them without -d. Docker-compose up only

Comment: And after you stop one service? (-d only gives you back the command prompt, -d: detach)

Comment: [I've stopped the one which yield `"I'm response from webapplication 1"`](https://i.imgur.com/4ITr6l1.jpg) and now i'm getting this https://i.imgur.com/jK1AS8q.jpg

Comment: Hi. did you see my answer ?

Comment: Yes, but I thought it solved your question, didn't it? So all good?

Comment: sorry, I don't really have time right now, but service load balancing is actually an interesting topic (I'm not an expert myself) but I believe it would definitely merit a question of it's own, maybe have a quick look at docker swarm and kubernetes before you post that question