# using a docker app to make a new directory in an external hard drive

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am using a docker container to execute a python script located at my host machine. The script should make a new directory at a target location.

When the target location is located under $HOME or $HOME/*, everything works. However, when I want to create a directory at `/media/my_name/external_drive`, the terminal says that **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/my_name'**

Here is the code I run

`sudo docker-compose run --rm --user="$(id -u):$(id -g)" main process_all.py`

Here is docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  main:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - PYTHONIOENCODING=utf_8
    init: true
    network_mode: host
```

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install some basic utilities
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    sudo \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    axel \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-root user and switch to it
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
 && chown -R user:user /app
RUN echo "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/90-user
USER user

# All users can use /home/user as their home directory
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user

# Install Miniconda
RUN curl -so ~/miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.4.10-Linux-x86_64.sh \
 && chmod +x ~/miniconda.sh \
 && ~/miniconda.sh -b -p ~/miniconda \
 && rm ~/miniconda.sh
ENV PATH=/home/user/miniconda/bin:$PATH

# Create a Python 3.6 environment
RUN /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda install conda-build \
 && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda create -y --name py36 python=3.6.4 \
 && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda clean -ya
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=py36
ENV CONDA_PREFIX=/home/user/miniconda/envs/$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
ENV PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/bin:$PATH

# Ensure conda version is at least 4.4.11
# (because of this issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6811)
ENV CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false
RUN conda install -y "conda>=4.4.11" && conda clean -ya

# Install FFmpeg
RUN conda install --no-update-deps -y -c conda-forge ffmpeg=3.2.4 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install NumPy
RUN conda install --no-update-deps -y numpy=1.13.3 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install build tools
RUN sudo apt-get update \
 && sudo apt-get install -y build-essential gfortran libncurses5-dev \
 && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Build and install CDF
RUN cd /tmp \
 && curl -O https://spdf.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/software/cdf/dist/cdf36_4/linux/cdf36_4-dist-all.tar.gz \
 && tar xzf cdf36_4-dist-all.tar.gz \
 && cd cdf36_4-dist \
 && make OS=linux ENV=gnu CURSES=yes FORTRAN=no UCOPTIONS=-O2 SHARED=yes all \
 && sudo make INSTALLDIR=/usr/local/cdf install

# Install other dependencies from pip
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Create empty SpacePy config (suppresses an annoying warning message)
RUN mkdir /home/user/.spacepy && echo "[spacepy]" > /home/user/.spacepy/spacepy.rc

# Copy scripts into the image
COPY --chown=user:user . /app

# Set the default command to python3
CMD ["python3"]
```

Comment: You want to create the directory inside the container or in your host machine ?

Comment: I want to create a folder at my external drive that connects to host machine

Comment: From memory, the external drive won't appear inside the container.  You have to mount it.   You can see what's going on by running the docker container manually and using interactive shell.  Run the bash command instead of python3

Comment: @Alex Get the mount path from the host and mount it in the container with volumes

Answer (score 0):

Untested, going by memory but I would debug the issue with an interactive version of your container.

Something like: 
`sudo docker run -t -i --rm --user="$(id -u):$(id -g)" main /bin/bash`

You'll get a bash shell.  Then you can debug it by

`cd /media`

`ls -l`

What I think you'll find is that the drive is probably not mounted.  Or, the user doesn't have permission to access it.

With regards to mounts, either pass it through from the host or create a volume mount.  I'm a little bit unsure about what you can do there because since I last used docker many changes around mounting and volume drivers were introduced.  But the documentation on the docker website is pretty good.  So experiment.

This is the cmd line reference for docker:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/
The key is to use the `-t -i` parameters to make it interactive.

Comment: I wasn't able to do this. The prompt says:

unable to find image 'main:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for main, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.elp'.

Comment: @Alex Put    `image: my.image.name:latest`   in your docker-compose  And instead of `main` use the `image-name:latest` in the run argument.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816456/how-to-tag-docker-image-with-docker-compose

Comment: @Alex - alternatively, just run `docker build -t my.image.name:latest .`  Then re-run the earlier command.