# Error response from daemon: No such image

Tags: docker

I am trying to run the following docker-compose yml in the github workflow, but I get the error of

```
Error response from daemon: No such image: ghcr.io/whats/app/backend/222243434353535353f
```

The error happens at the "Tag images" point below

The docker Ci file is

```
env:
    WEB_IMAGE_BASE: ghcr.io/$(echo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/backend
    WEB_IMAGE: ghcr.io/$(echo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/backend:$( echo $GITHUB_SHA )

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Docker Images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Prepare images
        run: |
          echo "WEB_IMAGE=$(echo ${{env.WEB_IMAGE}} )" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "WEB_IMAGE_BASE=$(echo ${{env.WEB_IMAGE_BASE}} )" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Build images
        run: |
          docker-compose -f ci.yml build backend

      - name: Tag images
        run: |
          docker tag ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE }}  ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE_BASE }}:latest
```

The ci.yml is

```
 ​version​: ​"​3.9​" 
  
 ​services​: 
 ​  ​backend​: 
 ​    ​image​: ​backend_prod
```

​

What am I doing wrong or please indicate how to fix this?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but those are [useless `echo`s in backticks](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to tag and image using as a source an image that doesn't exist.

The image `ghcr.io/whats/app/backend/222243434353535353f` wasn't created in any place.

You need to use as a source in tag command the built image result of docker-compose build.

Since you specify in your compose the `image: backend_prod` your image will be named by that.

Try to change the image in your docker compose to something like:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./backend/dockerfile
    image: backend_prod:local
```

And change your ci file:

```yaml
- name: Tag images
    run: |
      docker tag backend_prod:local ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE_BASE }}:latest
```

You can read more about the image tag in docker-compose [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33816456/1563297)

Comment: Can you edit your question with ci.yaml file?

Comment: I edit my answer. I didn't test it, but you can have the idea

Comment: Yes! that gave me some direction. The trick was to simply swap to image value in the ci.yml `image: "${WEB_IMAGE}"`and keep everything else the same.

Comment: Nice, if that helps please mark as answered tks